# Return different value depends on different condition

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got following code but it gives error "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'"
so what is the right way to write this code to give different return value depends on different if condition?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if category == "followings"{
        return usersRealNameFollowing.count
    }
    if category == "followers"{
        return usersRealNameFollower.count
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function has a return type then there should be a must return statement, mean function should return something always. Now in your case you are using if statement for both return statements which means that if both statements are wrong then there will be no return value.
Use if-else here that would be best option or

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           var count: Int()
           if category == "followings"{
                count = usersRealNameFollowing.count
           }else if category == "followers"{
                count = usersRealNameFollower.count
           }
    return count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another return in the very end **outside of any if statement**.

The reason it's giving you the error is that it's possible that both if statements are false and therefore there is nothing to return!

Or maybe you could try **switch**

```
switch(catagory)
{
    case "following":
        return usersRealNameFollowing.count;
    case "followers":
        return usersRealNameFollower.count;
    default:
        return -1;   //This will catch the situations that non of the conditions are met!
}
```

Good luck!!!

Comment: `enum Category { case following, followers }` this way there would be no default case. `switch category 
{
    case .following:
        return usersRealNameFollowing.count
    case .followers:
        return usersRealNameFollower.count
}`

Comment: Then what would happen if none of the conditions are met!?

Comment: Thats not possible considering that the enumeration is exhaustive

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think that's what's the OP asking for.

Comment: Sure he didn't ask but thats what he should do

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

You have no return statement in he case where neither `if` statement is true.

If there are only two options then you can just use an `else` statement. It would probably be better if `category` was an `enum` rather than a string since then you can be sure you have an exhaustive test using a `switch`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if category == "followings"{
        return usersRealNameFollowing.count
    } else {
        return usersRealNameFollower.count
    }
}
```

Comment: or simply `return category == "followings" ?  usersRealNameFollowing.count : usersRealNameFollower.count`

Comment: I think that an enumeration would be the correct approach .

Answer (score 0):

**let’s setup the methods for rendering the table view row height**

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if category == "followings"{
            return usersRealNameFollowing.count

        }else if category == "followers"{
            return usersRealNameFollower.count

        }else{
            return 0

        }


    }
```